# Facebook messenger chatbot shows "Check your connection and try again."

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, amazon-ec2, facebook-chatbot

Recently, I was trying to build a bot for myself. It works flawlessly when I'm using ngrok to test my bot locally, but when I deployed to AWS, I started seeing the error captured below occasionally, and causing no webhook request sent to my server from Facebook. I have no idea what could possibly go wrong. I have check the request going to my server with tcpflow as well, but there's no luck, it seems like Facebook just didn't send that particular request to my server. This is a really weird problem that happens in no particular point of my bot conversation flow. I always need to repeat my answer or my postback in order to get it to work.

Some basic server info (don't know if this matters) :

1. Availability zone: ap-southeast-1b
2. Type: t2.micro
3. CPU usage (at that moment): 4%

I would really appreciated if anyone could solve my mystery. Thanks.

FYI, I have reported this to Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1825253057751227

[image: connection error example]

Comment: I just googled this error ,Is it different from this : http://android.stackexchange.com/a/100886

Comment: Are you using a static ip on your aws instance? VPC?

Comment: I'm using an elastic IP for the AWS. Actually, I reported this to Facebook, and they acknowledged that this is a valid bug and assigned people to fix it, although is not fix yet

Comment: AWS is not the issue.

Comment: Well, is Facebook taking care of it? If so, i beleive they are in the best position to get a resolution for you in this matter.

Comment: Hi. Your server, which webhook request is working over http or https?

Comment: I have the same error too and what's weird is that It's only doing this for one of my persistent menu link.

Comment: I have experienced that as well. I suspected that is due to the persistent menu is not refreshed. I ended up deleting the conversation and restart the conversation again, and that seems to fix the problem. If that doesn't help, try remove the persistent menu completely and remove the get started button, then set get started button and then set the persistent menu again.

Answer (score 0):

Your webhook server has to work over valid **https** (not self signed).

My advice - add https to webhook server, using [cloudflare service](https://www.cloudflare.com/) (it`s free), or get a free valid certificate using [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)

Comment: I am using a letsencrypt actually but still encountering the same problem :(

Comment: Can you test requests to aws by curl or clients app like PostMaster. Have you see requests on aws by this test?

Comment: Yes, the error is occasional, normally I could see the request on AWS, just sometimes the error occurs

Answer (score 0):

If your error is occasional, I would recommend moving your instance size up from Micro, to at least Medium or Large and make it a [Dedicated](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/dedicated-instance.html) instance.  The resources required to run the letsencrypt client, combined with your bot traffic and noisy neighbors might overcome a shared micro instance.